# C++ string += produces different result

Tags: string, literals

Why this code below produce different result? What causes it?

```
  string s;
  s += 'a';
  s += 'b';
  cout<<s<<endl;//ab
  
  s = "";
  s += 'a' + 'b';
  cout<<s<<endl;//question mark character
```

Answer (score 2):

- when you do `'a'+'b'` expression becomes ascii value of 'a' + ascii value of 'b' i.e, `97+98` making the result = character whose ascii value is 195 (97+98).
- refer -> [https://www.javatpoint.com/ascii-value-in-c#:~:text=In%20C%20programming%20language%2C%20a,range%20from%200%20to%20127](https://www.javatpoint.com/ascii-value-in-c#:%7E:text=In%20C%20programming%20language%2C%20a,range%20from%200%20to%20127). and https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp